# Paypal in android studio (java): Problem communicating with servers

Tags: java, android, android-studio, paypal

I want to add a donation button to my app and it doesn't seems to be working the redirection to paypal. MAybe is my KEY or the tutorial that I was taking. If you could help me, that would be Awesome.

The permissions i'm ussing in the Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_INTERNET"/>
```

Donation, here i have a button and it redirects to paypal:

```
public class DonarActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button paymentBtn;
    private int PAYPAL_REQ_CODE = 12;
    //private static PayPalConfiguration paypalconfig = new PayPalConfiguration().environment(PayPalConfiguration.ENVIRONMENT_PRODUCTION); este es cuando esté listo
    private static PayPalConfiguration paypalconfig = new PayPalConfiguration().environment(PayPalConfiguration.ENVIRONMENT_SANDBOX)
            .clientId(PaypalConfig.PAYPAL_CLIENT_ID);


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_donar);

        paymentBtn=findViewById(R.id.paymentBtn);

        Intent intent = new Intent(this,PayPalService.class);
        intent.putExtra(PayPalService.EXTRA_PAYPAL_CONFIGURATION, paypalconfig);
        startService(intent);

        paymentBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                PaypalPaymentMethod();
            }
        });

    }
    private void PaypalPaymentMethod(){
        PayPalPayment payment = new PayPalPayment(new BigDecimal(10), "USD", "Test Payment", PayPalPayment.PAYMENT_INTENT_SALE);

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, PaymentActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(PayPalService.EXTRA_PAYPAL_CONFIGURATION, paypalconfig);
        intent.putExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_PAYMENT, payment);

        startActivityForResult(intent, PAYPAL_REQ_CODE);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode==PAYPAL_REQ_CODE){
            if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
                Toast.makeText(this, "El pago se hizo de manera exitosa!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "No se realizó el pago!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        stopService(new Intent(this, PayPalService.class));
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

PaypalConfig key:

```
public class PaypalConfig {
    public static final String PAYPAL_CLIENT_ID = "they say i dont show the key, so i'm putting this instead xd";

}
```

Error I'm getting when I click the button:

[image]

Finaly the Logcat, where it says that i'm having an error communicating with the server:

```
2021-04-02 11:01:53.668 18586-19785/com.example.voidsveils E/paypal.sdk: request failed with server response:socket failed: EPERM (Operation not permitted)
2021-04-02 11:01:53.668 18586-18586/com.example.voidsveils E/paypal.sdk: SERVER_COMMUNICATION_ERROR
```

Comment: Paypal Android Sdk is deprecated use Braintree

Comment: IDK what's that, but thank you, I'll study how to use it to get paypal

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comments, the Android SDK is deprecated. You cannot use it.

If you need a native SDK for PayPal payments, use Braintree.

Guide: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/archive/checkout/how-to/braintree-integration/ -- most other needed information will be on the Braintree site.

Do not attempt to create a Braintree gateway account, nor use Braintree gateway credentials.  Use the PayPal access token for the Braintree SDK.  Sandbox is at the bottom of [Developer -> Applications](https://www.paypal.com/signin?intent=developer&returnUri=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.paypal.com%2Fdeveloper%2Fapplications) , and later for live via https://www.paypal.com/api